# Cannot run elementary OS using rEFInd on HP Pavilion g7 2269wm

Tags: uefi, refind, amd, hp, radeon

This is the same laptop I previously asked questions about.So today I decided to install elementary.

First I installed elementary to USB using Rufus.

Then booted it from Windows Startup Menu and created the following partitions using GParted

/dev/sda6 - root ext4

/dev/sda7 - Linux swap

1. Ran `ubiquity -b` and installed elementary to sda6
2. Downloaded and extracted SHIM 0.2 to `/boot/efi/EFI/refind` and also installed rEFInd using the `--shim /boot/efi/EFI/rEFInd/SHIM.efi` and changed the rEFInd resolution to 1600 900 and enabled graphical boot.
3. Copied vmlinuz and initrd from sda6 to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`.
4. Rebooted and used F9 to select `shim.efi` and selected the correct certificate.
5. elementary OS shows as Ubuntu but does not boot.
6. Disabled secure boot and booted elementary (shows as Ubuntu).
7. I get a BusyBox shell and when I use RESUIB I get.

[image: laptop]

❤ elementary OS but can't get it to work on my laptop.I have elementary on another laptop and it is very nice

Comment: Looks related to the radeon driver. I am going to try upgrading the kernel from chroot and installing the drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed elementary OS using GRUB2 EFI bootloader and now it boots using GRUB2.But now when I boot GRUB2 from rEFInd after I select elementary OS it stays on a black screen for a few seconds (this happens normally) and after that it turns off.When booting from GRUB2 the screen is off until I put the laptop to sleep and turn it back on the screen is on.I could fix the screen not being on by installing `fglrx` from additional drivers.

Secure boot is **ON** now.

But I still can't boot it from rEFInd. Haven't yet tried disabling secure boot.

EDIT : elementary OS does not shutdown with secure boot **OFF** but boots to black screen (sound works) and requires me to put the laptop to sleep and turn in it again.

I am now going to try installing `flgrx` for kernel 4.4